# How to crop image based on InteractiveViewer aspect ratio?

Tags: flutter, dart

The goal is to crop the image based on aspect ratio of InteractionViewer. Without cropping packages. Interactions should reflect cropped image, like zooming and moving the image.

[image]

Comment: No, thats not the problem resizing based on the visible area is the problem, once you start zooming and moving.